# How to pull text from a webpage and display it in TextView

Tags: android, url, textview

I want to pull the text from this URL: http://www.weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/KORD.txt, save it to a string, then print that string in a TextView.

I am a complete newbie to android, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Reference [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418021/get-text-from-web-page-to-string) ReadWebpageAsyncTask will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

URL is invalid, or my country is blocked

**put this BEFORE onCreate():**

```
private TextView outtext;
private String HTML;
```

**And add lines between comments into onCreate like this:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /*FROM HERE*/
        outtext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1); //change id if needed!!!

            try { 
            getHTML();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        outtext.setText("" + HTML);
        /*TO HERE*/
    }
```

**now this is the method you will use to download content:**

```
 private void getHTML() throws throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 

        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/KORD.txt"); //URL!
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            String result = "";

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line + "\n";
                HTML = result;
            }

        }
```

**You also need to set permission in AndroidManifest.xml to use internet:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Also this is NOT the best way to do this. When you open your app it will freeze until it loads from website, so you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to help you out there.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418021/get-text-from-web-page-to-string).

**DownloadWebPageTask** class will do the trick and don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to **AndroidManifest.xml** to permit the use of the Internet.