# Fill android app table from website table

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, sqlite

Lets say i have an table in an android app, and i have a website with a table (text & hyperlinks) that gets updated hourly. is there a simple way to get the data from the website table to the android table thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an HTTP get request to the website with the table and parse it as a string, extracting the text within the `<table></table>` elements. Perhaps the following post may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418351/2557554