# RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am accepting address by user and then trying to get latitude and longitude for that i am using AsyncTask.

Every time i am getting : `RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

And facing exception at this line: `Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);`

**Log:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(810): Process: app.android.fields, PID: 810
E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at app.android.users.MainActivity$RegisterUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:326)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at app.android.users.MainActivity$RegisterUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 4 more
```

**Code:**

```
@Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                ............

                strNewClientCompleteAddress = 
                    strNewClientAddress+" "+strNewClientCity+" "+" "+strNewClientState+" "+strNewClientPostalCode;
                Log.v("strNewClientCompleteAddress:",strNewClientCompleteAddress);


                Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);

                try {                                                
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(strNewClientCompleteAddress, 1);                           
                    if(addresses != null) {                            
                        Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                        lat = fetchedAddress.getLatitude();
                        lng = fetchedAddress.getLongitude();
                        Log.v("try-if", "ok great work");                       
                    }
                    else {                      
                        Log.v("try-else", "something wrong");                       
                    }

                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();                                    
                        Log.v("catch", "Could not get address....!");                       
                    }                           

                strLat = String.valueOf(lat);
                Log.v("lat:", strLat);
                strLng = String.valueOf(lng);
                Log.v("lng:", strLng);

               ........................
           }
```

**Updated code:**

```
..............
if((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {                
    Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
    lat = fetchedAddress.getLatitude();
    lng = fetchedAddress.getLongitude();
    Log.v("try-if", "ok great work");                       
}
..............
```

**Log:**

```
V/strNewClientCompleteAddress:(1119): 1701 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View  CA 94043
V/try-else(1119): something wrong
V/lat:(1119): 0.0
V/lng:(1119): 0.0
```

Comment: If your `strNewClientCompleteAddress`  is not valid then addresses might be NULL. and remember one thing `.getFromLocationName()` not return Location all time.

Comment: your logcat clearly indicating--> `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`   First check the address.size()>0 then access it.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532520 where the issue was the url needed to start with http:// and the app needed INTERNET use-permission

Comment: @Rustam now i am not getting any exception and also unable to get latitude and longitude, i have posted updated code and log please check

Comment: @Sun You should use either `addresses.isEmpty() == false` or `addresses.size() > 0`. Both does the same.

Comment: @PankajKumar yeah i removed addresses.isEmpty() == false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check `addresses.size() > 0`

```
 if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
   Address address=addresses.get(0);
 }
```

Comment: now i am not getting any exception and also unable to get latitude and longitude

Comment: check your `strNewClientCompleteAddress` is valid or not.

Comment: i posted updated code and log as well please check above, and getting V/strNewClientCompleteAddress:(1119): 1701 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View  CA 94043

Answer (score 1):

the addresse array size is zero.it means your address array contains no values and you are trying to get the first position of the array value.

before get the value from array need to check null and size like below

```
 if(addresses!=null && addresses.size()>0)
 { 
 Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
 }else
  {
       return yourcondition; 
   }
```

Comment: now i am not getting any exception and also unable to get latitude and longitude, i have posted updated code and log please check

Comment: if you need to access current location add this permission to your menifest and try once    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />