# How parse JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json

Anyone know how to read JSONObjcet from url?

Comment: I wouldnt put your api key public. edit your question and take it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the answer from the webbapge as `String`. For example see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418021/get-text-from-web-page-to-string). Then you can parse the answer with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).