# How to JSON parser from web page on android?

Tags: android, json

I don't know how to use **JSON** **parser** from web

first, In my website only text

```
{"name":"hellohello", "age":"19","address":"123123123","phone":"00000"}
```

and I know use `JSON parser` on android

```
TextView textmessage;
String mStrJson;
public void onParser() {
   String strData ="";
   try {
       JSONArray json = new JSONArray(mStr);
       for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject object = json.getJSONObject(i);
           strData += object.getString("name") + " - " + "\n" + object.getInt("age") + "\n";
       }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       Log.d("tag", "parse error");
   }
   textmessage.setText(strData);
 }
```

but I don't know how to get web page text?

please advice for me thanks.

Comment: Use `HttpURLConnection` or `Volley` for getting response for webpage

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418021/get-text-from-web-page-to-string)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK    thanks, but  recently I have get web page text I want  how to this text json parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method.

```
public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            c.setReadTimeout(5000);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();
            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```